# Getting access to the location services

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to acquire the current lat/long from a WP7 device, and I've found a few tutorials on doing this which I'm using as a basis.

However, watching the StatusChanged events in Visual Studio I see it change from Initializing to Disabled.  Looking at the Permission, it says Denied.  It never gets to PositionChanged.

Reading the docs for the permissions, they just say that the user may have disabled location services on the phone.  But that's not the case here, they're definitely enabled under settings, and I've verified that the Maps app is working.

Am I missing something obvious?  Is there a way for users to selectively enable/disable location services for apps?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got the Location capability in your WMAppManifest.xml file?

```
  <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: I do now!  Thanks very much.  I knew it was probably something pretty stupid. :)